# Magento 2.4.4 p4 save attribute brand logo error show A technical problem with the server created an error

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, magento2.4.4

- Magento 2.4.4 p4
- add brand option logo edit attribute page
  error show -> A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to
  continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again
  later.

Comment: check log files